# Why am I getting 'Unable to locate element' error for 'MainContent_txtTaskName'?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, error-handling, cucumber, ui-automation

I'm struggling with the following issue and I hope that someone can help me with a solution.
In my PO class, I've added the below webelement and use it in order to type text within the input field; all the webelements are within iframe;

```
@FindBy(css = "input[id=\"MainContent_txtTaskName\"]")
public WebElement alertNameInputField;
 public void typeAlertName() {
    try {
        driver.switchTo().frame(alertNameInputField);
    } catch (NoSuchFrameException e) {
        System.out.println("Handled NoSuchFrameException");
    }
    alertNameInputField.sendKeys("School closed on Monday");
    driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
}
```

The flow consists of 5 steps. Once having the text written within the input field(on Step 1), in the StepDefinitions class, I'm saving it within a String variable and compare it with  the same text displayed on Step 3(it is neccesary to make sure that the text is correctly displayed the third step).

```
@And("verifies if Alert Name on step 3 is the same as on Step 1")
public void verifyAlertNamesValues() {
   String step1AlertName = String.valueOf(swiftk12.alertNameInputField.getText());
    String step3AlertName = swiftk12.getStep3AlertNameText();
    Assert.assertEquals("The Alert Name on Step 1 is not the same as on Step 3", step3AlertName, step1AlertName);
}
```

Once running the test, it fails on the mentioned step(which is currently the last one out of 18) with the below error message:

```
**Step failed
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element:          {"method":"css selector","selector":"input[id="MainContent_txtTaskName"]"}**
```

I can't figure it out why the webelement is no longer found since I'm only using within the step to get its text and save it within the String variable.

What am I missing? Looking forward to receiving help on this matter!

Thank you!

I've used wait methods, I've changed getText() to getAttribute("value"), I've tried a lot of things to get the text from Step 1 and compare it with the one displayed on Step 3.

Comment: This is very confusing. where exactly the exception come from?
and you sure that you don't need to switch to an Iframe again?

Comment: FYI: wrapping `getText` with `String.valueOf` is redundant

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 0):

Vlad, check if the elements sits inside of Iframe. If the element is wrapped in an Iframe - you need to tell Selenium to focus on the relevant Iframe:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(0);
```

Or

```
driver.switchTo().frame("id of the Iframe");
```

Selenium ignores any element that is wrapped inside Iframe by default. You must change the focus in order to interact with such elements.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I've tried that within the below code, but still doesn't working
I still get the same error: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element

Comment: Make sure you moved to the correct Iframe + revalidate the CSS expression of the element you need.

Answer (score 0):

Will adjusting the code like below will help your issue.

```
@FindBy(css = "input[id=\"MainContent_txtTaskName\"]")
public WebElement alertNameInputField;
 public String typeAlertName() {
    try {
        driver.switchTo().frame(alertNameInputField);
    } catch (NoSuchFrameException e) {
        System.out.println("Handled NoSuchFrameException");
    }
    alertNameInputField.sendKeys("School closed on Monday");
    String alertValue = alertNameInputField.getText();
    return alertValue;
    driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
}
```

Above I directly retrieving the value typed in the text field and then you can compare it with the expected value by calling the method itself from the below code.

```
@And("verifies if Alert Name on step 3 is the same as on Step 1")
public void verifyAlertNamesValues() {
   String step1AlertName = typeAlertName();
   String step3AlertName = swiftk12.getStep3AlertNameText();
   Assert.assertEquals("The Alert Name on Step 1 is not the same as on Step 3", step3AlertName, step1AlertName);
```

}

Comment: What is mean by you as 'swiftk12' in your code?

Comment: Thank you for the suggested solution! Unfortunately, the test still fails with the same error message. I'll try something else.

Comment: Could you check using below css selection will work for element capture.

@FindBy(css = "input#MainContent_txtTaskName")

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but still no success.